# How did "doblar" come to mean "turn"?

Tags: etimología

*Inspired by [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14439/origin-of-the-verb-doppiare-in-the-nautical-slang) on Italian SE*

In Italian, French and English (and probably other languages) there are words cognate to Spanish *doblar*, which mean "to round (a cape, an isle etc.)" in the narrow nautical sense: "to double Cape Horn", *doppiare il Capo di Buona Speranza* etc.

The Treccani dictionary [states](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/doppiare1/) that at least in Italian, it's a calque from Spanish:

> 2, è un calco dello spagn. *doblar*

I don't speak Spanish, so I might be wrong, but my understanding is that, unlike the other languages, *doblar* in Spanish means "to change the direction of movement" in the general sense, and not just in this narrow nautical sense.

Etymological dictionaries do state that it came from Latin *duplus* ("double"), but don't expand on the semantic development of this word: how exacly the meaning shifted from "to double" to "to turn". At least I could not find anything. DRAE only mentions *Del lat. duplāre, de duplus 'doble'.*, same for Wiktionary.

So how exactly did *doblar* came to mean "to turn" in Spanish?

Answer (score 3):

It seems clear that the original meaning is "to duplicate".

[Entry #4 in the DLE](https://dle.rae.es/doblar) may give a hint on its evolution. It can be translated as "to fold". By folding paper (papyrus?) or tissue you duplicate the number of layers.

In order to do that you need to bend it, which takes us to Entry #6.

And when, instead of bending paper, you bend your trajectory, you get the meanings #10 and #11.

Just a hypothesis.

Comment: In Italian it is similar, the sharp English distinction beetween *to fold* and *to turn* doesn't exist. *Piegare* (*doblar* in Italian) means both *to fold* or *to turn*: *piegò a destra* intr. , is *Doblé a la derecha*.

Answer (score 0):

*Doblar* has several meanings and, according to its etymology, they all fall within the origin of the word.

#### DOBLAR

> El verbo **doblar** (aumentar en dos, torcer algo encorvándolo, volver una cosa sobre otra) viene del latín *duplare*, compuesta con ***duplus* (doble)** y la terminación -are usada para formar verbos.
>
> La palabra ***duplus*** nos dio: doble, doblete, doblez, etc. Se relaciona con dos raíces indoeuropeas.
>
> - La primera es ***dwo* (dos)** que daría diploma y dipluro.
> - La segunda es ***pel-5* (doblar, plegar)**, que parece ser una
>   variante de *plek* (plegar, trenzar).

<sub>*Source [etimologiasdechile.net](https://etimologias.dechile.net/?doblar#:%7E:text=El%20verbo%20doblar%20)*</sub>

### Edit

I think the relationship between *to fold* and *to turn* may be related to the etymology described in the first part of the answer.

The root ***plek*** has the same origin as **[*plicāre*](https://etimologias.dechile.net/?llegar)** which means *doblar* and is the origin of *llegar* (to arrive). Therefore, putting both meanings together, it is not difficult to interpret the mixture between *to arrive* and *to turn* that results in *doblar* as to turn.

<sub>*See [from plicare to llegar](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/from-plic%C4%81re-to-llegar-semantic-shift.3562388/)*</sub>

> **plicāre** (Latin)
> Inflection of plicō (present active infinitive)
> Inflection of plicō (second-person singular present passive imperative)
> Inflection of plicō (second-person singular present passive indicative)
> **plico** (Latin)
>
> From Proto-Indo-European *pleḱ-‎ ("to plait, to weave") (with i from the compounded forms). Cognate with Latin plectō.
> (transitive) I fold, bend or flex; I roll up
> (transitive) I arrive (this meaning comes from sailors, for whom the folding of a ship’s sails meant arrival on land)

Comment: According to most sources, Latin _duplus_ and _duplex_, although similar in meaning, come from two different PIE roots. This dictionary states that _duplus_ comes from the same root that gave _-plex_, which contradicts that. Also, you answer seems to assume that _duplare_ meant "to turn" in some pre-Spanish stage of Latin as well. Do you know of any examples of such usage?

Comment: Sorry, the link was wrong, fixed. Where do you read Duplex?

Comment: Your link mentions _*pleḱ_ which gave _duplex_ (and other words in _-plex_) but not _duplus_ in Latin (at least according to most sources). This source seems to assume that it gave _duplus_ as well.

Comment: But my larger question is how the word meaning "to double" came to mean "to turn". Just to clarify, are you saying it was this way in Latin already, or this is a later innovation?

Comment: Answer updated.-